# Could someone assist me updating a sql server 2019 code to work with sql server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have this code that runs perfectly on sql server 2019 but alot of the functions were only introduced in i think the 2017+ versions. Im using sql server 2008r2 and would liek to know if someone could help me re-code it to run. thanks.

```
        declare 
            @s1 varchar(100)='The Elf on the Shelf: A Christmas Musical. (Touring)',
            @s2 varchar(100)='The Elf on the Shelf Musical, Baltimore';
        
        with words as (
          select 1 s, Replace(Translate(value,'!"*():;,.','|||||||||'),'|','') word
          from String_Split(@s1,' ')
          union all
          select 2, Replace(Translate(value,'!"*():;,.','|||||||||'),'|','')
        from String_Split(@s2,' ')
        ), matching as (
            select *, Row_Number() over(partition by word order by s) rn
            from words
        ), final as (
            select * , Count(*) over(partition by word, s) repeating, Count(*) over() * 1.0 totwords, sum(Iif(s=1,1,0)) over() s1words
            from matching
            outer apply(values(Iif(rn=2 and rn=s,1,0)))x(p)
        )
        select (Sum (p) + max(case when s=1 and repeating>1 then repeating end))
            / Max(Iif(totwords/s1words>0.5, totwords-s1words, s1words)) * 100 [Matching Words %]
        from final
```

Comment: ya im just hitting a brick wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the same work in SQL Server 2008 R2, it's going to be a lot less efficient, and you're going to need some helper user-defined functions created.

First is a generic one for splitting strings, to replace `STRING_SPLIT()`. There are literally hundreds of different ones out there, but be aware that some might not properly handle space as a delimiter. This is just the first one I grabbed from [my own stash of resources on splitting strings](https://sqlblog.org/split):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
   @List       nvarchar(max),
   @Delimiter  nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value(N'(./text())[1]', N'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, N'<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, N'</i><i>') 
          + N'</i>').query(N'.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

Next we'll need a function that iterates through a string, one character at a time, and removes bad characters (this replace `TRANSLATE()` in your existing code). Some solutions out there will use a while loop and patindex, and that's ok, but others will just say to nest 17 `REPLACE()` calls and that makes for code that is impossible to read and maintain. Here is the one I came up with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CreateCleanString 
(
  @String        nvarchar(4000),
  @IgnorePattern nvarchar(255) 
)
RETURNS @Set TABLE
(
  listpos   int,
  character nchar(1)
)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @pos int, @ThisCharacter nchar(1);
  SET @pos = 1

  WHILE @pos <= LEN(@String)
  BEGIN
    SET @ThisCharacter = SUBSTRING(@String, @pos, 1);
    IF @IgnorePattern NOT LIKE N'%' + @ThisCharacter + N'%'
    BEGIN
      INSERT @Set(listpos, character)
        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(listpos) + 1, 1), SUBSTRING(@String, @pos, 1)
        FROM @Set;
    END
    SET @pos = @pos + 1;
  END
  RETURN;
END
GO
```

With those two in place, you can now write this much more complicated query to achieve the results. I'm not going to enumerate all of the differences, but they start on the very first line (SQL Server 2008 didn't support inline declare/set), and continue through all the `IIF()` references rewritten as [`CASE` expressions](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression).

```
DECLARE @pattern nvarchar(255), @s1 nvarchar(4000), @s2 nvarchar(4000);
          
SELECT @pattern = N'!"*():;,.',
       @s1 = N'The Elf on the Shelf: A Christmas Musical. (Touring)',
       @s2 = N'The Elf on the Shelf Musical, Baltimore';

;WITH clean_src AS -- break it apart by character and get rid of bad ones
(
  SELECT src.s, src.str, c.listpos, c.character 
    FROM (VALUES(1,@s1),(2,@s2)) AS src(s,str) 
    CROSS APPLY dbo.CreateCleanString(src.str, @pattern) AS c),
clean_output AS -- put it back together
(
  SELECT s, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s ORDER BY c.listpos), 
    CleanString = (SELECT clean_src.character 
      FROM clean_src WHERE s = c.s ORDER BY c.listpos 
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(4000)') 
    FROM clean_src AS c),
words AS -- now break it apart again, this time into words
(
  SELECT s, word = Item, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY s) 
    FROM clean_output CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(CleanString, ' ')
    WHERE rn = 1),
final AS -- do some matching and generate aggregates
(
  SELECT s, word, rn, x.p,
    repeating = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY word, s),
    totwords  = COUNT(*) OVER() * 1.0, 
    s1words   = SUM(CASE WHEN s = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER()
  FROM words 
  OUTER APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN rn = 2 and rn = s THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS x(p)
)
SELECT [Matching Words %] = (SUM(p) 
  + MAX(CASE WHEN s = 1 AND repeating > 1  THEN repeating END))
  / MAX(CASE WHEN totwords / s1words > 0.5 THEN totwords - s1words 
  ELSE s1words END) * 100 
FROM final;
```

- Original version on SQL Server 2019: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e207f62df8482d647b3b61d8cbe123cf)
- This method, on the oldest version supported (2014): [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a74d6a4c7bf423ff9b9e029e811ad482)

Now, I don't have a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance to test this on, and in fact I asked around and I don't know anybody else who does either. It really is time to think about finally upgrading, IMHO.

Comment: Perfect! Works for me! Thanks so much!